# Most elegant/standard way to scan from file in Java NOT in the main method

Tags: java, io

What is the standard way to scan data from a file not inside of the main method?  To clarify, I have an input file and want to use a scanner to read data from it, but can not do so in the main method, but still want access to it in the main method without having to construct a new Scanner.

Comment: Make a method either in your object, or just a static method that can be called from your main. Pass the method a scanner object from main. Have this method return the data you want to access in main

Comment: And you don't have to *use* an object in the same method that you created it. Hint: parameters...

Comment: use of another `public void myScanner` and scan in there and call `myScanner` from main method to get acces to it?

Comment: Thank you, but I'm still not 100% sure how to do this.  If I create a scanner in another method, how can I return it to the main method without constructing a new Scanner?  Could someone post a code example?